# Aggregate every id between columns with the same value and between dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Having this table i need help to select values from id 3898 (tipologia_enum ='RECEITA')
to 4021 (tipologia_enum = 'RECEITA') but also include id 4060 because its date (column "data") its less than the date from the last value (id 4021). I want this information per row because there are more rows (below id 3898).

I was thinking of aggregate function ("string_agg", i'm using postrgres 15).

**EDITED:**
I created an example here:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jEnMScBf2BDJU3HpS7BkTs/7
In this example i would like to consider id 4060 because the date is lower than the last 'RECEITA' but i dont want to consider id 4061 because the date is (greater or) equal to the last 'RECEITA'.

The ideal output is something like this because from id 3899 to 4020 and 4060 is the same period of expenses... (the breakpoint is 'RECEITA' but also the date)

| date_part | date_part | tipologia_enum | ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024 | 1 | DESPESA | 3899,3900,3914,3915,3916,3917,3918,3919,3920,3921,3922,3924,3945,3950,3951,3952,3953,3954,3955,3956,3957,3958,3959,3960,3961,3962,3963,3964,3965,3987,3988,3989,3990,3991,3992,3993,4001,4002,4003,4004,4005,4006,4007,4008,4009,4010,4011,4012,4013,4016,4017,4018,4020,4060 |
| 2024 | 2 | DESPESA | 4061 |

Comment: Hi - please don't use images (as no-one can copy the data if they want to try a solution) - use editable text formatted as a table. Just to clarify: you want all data between the minimum date for  id 3898 and the maximum date for id 4021?

Comment: Hello, I'm very sorry! To clarify it's a bit difficult to explain, I want to aggregate the primary keys between the column value = 'RECEITA' but also with the date taken into consideration (see the example)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "between the column value = 'RECEITA'"? Do you mean all IDs between the minimum and maximum ID values for RECEITA? Or do you mean between the minimum and maximum dates for RECEITA? Or something else?

Comment: Couple of remarks... in your period you include both the upper and lower "RECEITA". Should that not be one of the two? like 3899, [...], 4021 instead of 3898, [...], 4021? Also, if you include records which have a higher id then end-"RECEIPA" (if their date is lower), should they then still also be included in the next "RECEIPA"-batch? If not then it just becomes just getting start and end date of each RECEIPA-batch and grouping based on this date.

Comment: I mean, RECEITA its like a salary which will have an entry for every month. But i want the ids of other things between that.
Imagine (like the images) i have RECEITA in 2023-12-20 and i have another RECEITA in 2024-01-22, I want to catch all my ids between that period but with the date included too. In the example i have an EXPENSE (id 4060) in 2024-01-21 but i want to include that too because the date is lower that the last RECEITA (which was on 2024-01-22)

Comment: I edited my quesiton with an example in db-fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Hey your question is not that clear to me.
You mention the `tipologia_enum`but it doesn't seem to impact the query when I look at your result table. Could you explain further what you think it should add to the query?

Based on your starting and result table I grouped the values by year and month and aggregated the IDs. Is this what you are searching for?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    extract(year from d.data),
    extract(month from d.data),
    STRING_AGG(CAST(d.id as text), ',' order by id) as ids
FROM
    MyTable
group by
    extract(year from d.data),
    extract(month from d.data)
order by
    extract(year from d.data),
    extract(month from d.data) asc
```

Comment: Year() and Month() are not postgresql syntax. You should convert to extract form. Also this is now what OP means, i think. But is indeed not very clear in original post.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's something like that but i tried to explain better in my last comment, see if its clear for you.

Comment: @LuisOliveira I see your DBFiddle. So what is wrong with the current output of the DB Fiddle or what is wrong with my output.  That way I can change it to fit your requirement. Maybe you could add a table with the correct output that you want.

Comment: @LuisOliveira Alright so, first question. In the output table you have a 2024 row with month = 2, but there isn't a single row in your dataset that's in February. So how am I supposed to deduce you want the row with id = 4061 to map to the 2nd month? Since that row has the date = '2024-01-22'

Comment: Yea i know but this is my idea of solution to the problem, it could be something else i don't know. Maybe you have another idea... I am open to suggestions.
It could be, if that's easier, two rows with the same month ("1"):
2024 | 1 | 4061